# When is java used in a Dynamic Web Project?

Tags: java

I loved the diversity of java ever since my first time using it. With that said I have tried to use it to its fullest. I am in the development of a computer game, android game, and website. Yay me. My problem is that I've been learning html, css, and a little bit of javascript for use in an eclipse dynamic web project. I don't see where or how java plays into the equation. To summarize I am asking for an explanation of where java would be used inside of a dynamic web project and maybe an example.

What I have now: `http://192.168.43.194:8080/Pointlight_Productions/homepage.html`

Comment: Read up on Servlets and Servlet containers.

Comment: I have seen servlets before I just don't know how they are used and implemented.

Comment: That's why you [_read up_](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html) on it.

Comment: I'm here now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719004/understanding-servlet-container

Comment: Also, [our servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) page.

Comment: so tomcat is a servlet container apparently so i have that already...

Comment: still lost, I found that stuff hard to read.

Comment: that isn't constructive and rude because ive been doing java for a year and a half but just started ee development

Comment: What answer are you looking for? `A Servlet is a Java application programming interface (API) running on the server machine which can intercept requests made by the client and can generate/send a response accordingly.` So you use Java Servlets in a Dynamic Web Project to receive requests and generate responses.

Comment: I specificly said `I am asking for an explanation of where java would be used inside of a dynamic web project and maybe an example.` but you knew that because you posted comments not answers

Comment: now could i get an example?\

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian Java will usually be used on the server side (eg. servlets, Play!, etc..). Unless you have a good reason to use servlets for your server side application, take time to explore other (more lightweight) avenues like, eg. node.js which should be very attractive if you are already well versed in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Dynamic web project* is an Eclipse term, as far I know. When you create a *Dynamic Web Project*, you're typically telling Eclipse to manage your project as if it were intended as a web application to be deployed on a Servlet container. Eclipse will compile your source and resources and produce a `.war` file that you deploy in a Servlet container (Tomcat, Glassfish, etc.)

A Servlet container is written in Java. But this is provided. You write Java server code. In other words, you implement a number of `Servlet` classes that handle requests and generate responses.

For example, you might want to show a customized page for a user in an HTTP web application. Your `Servlet` would receive an HTTP request containing the name of the user. Your `Servlet` (or the services it depends on) would look up the name in some database, retrieve all the information for the corresponding user, and generate an HTTP response, possibly HTML, that would display that information.

Reading:

- [Our `Servlet` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)
- [Java EE 7 Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets.htm)