# Not able to run a Vaadin application on remote server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vaadin, vaadin7

I am building a Vaadin application with Java. Here is the folder structure.

```
- com
-- my
--- WebTool
---- ToolUI.java
---- View_1.java
---- View_2.java
```

The entry point to the application is *ToolUI.java* and has the method *init()* that takes *VaadinRequest* as a parameter. It is this file where I add the views *Views_1* and *View_2* as views of the application and add navigations among them. Everything runs great when I run the application via the Eclipse IDE.

Now I have a requirement that I have to deploy this application on a remote server. So I created a war of the project and deployed on the server by the name 
MyWebTool.war.

Now when I try running the war with the command

```
java -jar MyWebTool.war
```

it gives me the error: *Can't execute war no main manifest attribute, in MyWebTool.war*

I am not sure what to add the main class as since the init method gets invoked and sets the app running. So I put a blank main function inside the MyWebToolUI.java and added this dependency in the pom.xml file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.my.WebTool.ToolUI</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
      <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
      <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But now when trying to run the application it says *Could not find or load main class com.my.WebTool.ToolUI*

Can please somebody shed light on this? I don't know if I am missing something simple here but at this point, I am stuck. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running war packaged applications, you will need a [servlet container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719004/understanding-servlet-container).
The servlet container provides all the basic infrastructure needed to run java based web applications.

One of the most common ways to do this, is to [deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7) the war file to a [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) installation.